# Changing interactive mode Edge Shape in JUNG

Tags: shapes, edges, jung

I am aware of the ability using an EdgeShapeTransformer to change the look of edges:

```
vv.getRenderContext().setEdgeShapeTransformer(new EdgeShape.Line()); // for example
```

However I am looking for how to change the way the line looks while dragging from one node to another to create an edge interactively. By default the 'hovering' edge which is not yet linked to another node is a large curved line. See the example [here](http://jung.sourceforge.net/applet/grapheditordemo.html) for what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

CubicCurveEdgeEffects is where it is done. There is an EdgeEffects interface that can be implemented to do other things instead. It is used by the SimpleEdgeSupport class via the EditingGraphMousePlugin.
(Credit to Tom Nelson, offline communication.)

Comment: Thank you Joshua, this is more information than I could get hold of. However could you guide me as to how I could change this edge shape? A link to an example would even be great.